# Cloud Firestore : add and update data from an API

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an Android app which shows on a map the locations of bicycle stations in a city. The locations are provided by this API as a JSON File [here](http://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/velib).
I want to save these locations in google cloud firestore, and then connect firestore to my app.
My question is how can i write and update (in realtime or periodically) in the cloud firestore ? i tried the firebase functions but i cant get a result.

Comment: i hope u have looked into the firebase SDK for the firestore as well?.

Comment: yes i did, but all the examples shown in the documentation are about writing from an app or entering data manually. i cant find examples or adding data from an API

Answer (score 1):

You need some rest API services to perform **CRUD** operations in case of android u can any Networking library to perform these operations. Some are Retrofit, Volley, HttpsUrlConnection.

If you hit any of the endpoints from the any networking library from **java**, **python**, **php**, **Node** or any language you should be able to change the data in your DB

Here is some rest documentation to **create** a document in the firebase cloud store.

```
 https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{parent=projects/*/databases/*/documents/**}/{collectionId}
```

delete

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{name=projects/*/databases/*/documents/*/**}
```

here is rest of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest)

Just hit these api endpoints from some development platform android,ios,backend,frontend or from anywhere it should work.